# JavaScript / jQuery: get numeric weekday value of date string

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, weekday

I have a field with a date value that is always formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. 
How can I get the weekday value of this field value.

Example: If the date in the field is a Monday the result should be 1, if it's Tuesday it should be 2 and so on.

**I tried the following but this returns NaN for me:**

```
var n = new Date( $('#myFieldID').val() );
var w = n.getDay();
```

**I am using Moment.js to create the date that goes into that field:**

```
var dateNow = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$('#myFieldID').val(dateNow);
```

This works and would fill in 2014-02-13 for the 13th of February 2014.

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim

Comment: What does `$('#myFieldID').val()` evaluate to?

Comment: @KyleMuir, OP said a value formatted as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: He said the format it _should_ be in but who knows what's actually being put into that field and as it's omitted it makes the problem infinitely harder than it needs to be.

Comment: For example: `var n = new Date('2014-01-01'); n.getDay()` n = 3 in any console, so my assumption is that the input is incorrect.

Comment: You're right about that.

Comment: I am using Moment.js to create the date that goes into the field. I'll update my post.

Comment: This question has been tagged with Workday. How this question is related with Workday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Moment.js also has a weekday function built-in which resolved the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same exact syntax you did in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELTjL/).

```
var n = new Date($('#date').val());
var w = n.getDay();
console.log(w);
```

Without us knowing what '#myFieldID' is, we can't get the question, but the syntax you used is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post. My guess is that I need to wrap the date in single quotes or something like that ?

Comment: `var dateNow = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
$('#myFieldID').val(dateNow);`

You are missing an endquote for #myFieldID.

Comment: Thanks, that was just the copy / pasting on the site here.